# 24 topics of Samkhya

Tags: samkhya

Vashishta [describes](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c006.htm) the 24 topics of Sankhya to Janaka..

> From *Prakriti*, they say, O monarch, the second principle called *Mahat*, is produced. It is heard by us that from Mahat flows the third principle called *Consciousness*. The Sankhyas blessed with sight of the Soul say that from Consciousness flow the five subtile essence of *sound, form, touch, taste, and scent*. All these eight they call by the name of Prakriti. The modifications of these eight are sixteen in number. They are the five gross essence of *space, light, earth, water, and wind, and the ten senses of action and of knowledge* including the mind. Men of wisdom devoted to the Sankhya path and conversant with all its ordinances and dispensations regard these four and twenty topics as embracing the whole range of Sankhya enquiry.

How does these add up to 24? Pakriti, Mahat, Consciousness, sound, form, touch, taste, and scent, space, light, earth, water, and wind become 13?
If the last 10 above are counted twice, for knowledge and ignorance each, that will be 20+3.

Comment: See this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/25049/4732